# using scons to run a perl script (which autogenerates a series of files) then compile these files and create a static library

Tags: python, makefile, scons

I'm porting our project from make to scons and I'm encountering a few issues.
We have a number of perl scripts that we run through make which generate a series of C++ source files.
These files are then compiled into a static library.

At present I can run the perl scripts through scons and compile the files with a bit of additional python scripting, however, it seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Also I'm finding that the scons script doesn't seem to  be executed linearly.  Parts of the script are being executed out of order.

Here is my sconscript;

```
// SConscript file

import platform
import os
import glob
import time
Import('directEnv')
cohEnv = directEnv.Clone()

includePath = Split("""
#Direct/include
#Direct/libsrc/liblog
#Direct/libsrc/libtime
#tools/include
#Direct/include
#Direct/engine
""")

if platform.machine() == 'i686':
    includePath = includePath + ['#tools/coh-cpp-v3.6-linux-x32/coherence-cpp/include']

else:
    includePath = includePath + ['#tools/cohe-cpp-v3.5.3b465-linux-x64/coherence cpp/include']

cohFiles = Split("""
#Direct/include/IntApi.h 
#Direct/include/MessagingApiRisk.h 
#Direct/include/MessagingApiCommon.h
""")

cohEnv.Append(CPPPATH = includePath)
cohEnv.Append(CCFLAGS = '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DUTPBRIDGE -Wno-unused-variable')
cohEnv.Append(LIBS = Split('nsl m rt'))

#
# Run Perl script - this generates approx 30 c++ source files
#

Clean('.', '#Direct/coh/cpp/CohMsgObj_0.cc')
temp1 = cohEnv.RunPerl('#Direct/coh/cpp/CohMsgObj_0.cc', '#Direct/coh/BuildCohObjs.pl')
Depends(temp1, '#Direct/coh/BuildCoherenceObjs.pl')
Depends(temp1, '#Direct/include/IntApi.h')

#
# Run Perl script - this generates 3 c++ source files
#

Clean('.', '#Direct/coh/cpp/Print_BinV4.cc')
temp2 = cohEnv.RunPerl('#Direct/coh/cpp/Print_BinV4.cc', '#Direct/coh/BuildCohObjsRisk.pl')
Depends(temp2, '#Direct/coh/BuildCohObjsRisk.pl')

#
# Build the object and library
#

print os.getcwd()
os.chdir('../../cpp')
path = os.getcwd()
print path

# 
# get all the c++ source files that we need to compile
#

List = []
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.cc')):
    List.append(infile)

count = 0    
suffix = ".cc"
ObjectList = []

#
# create objects for each source file
# I'm trying to create variables dynamically - incase the files which generates the 
# source files change - I don;t want to manually list everything that needs to be compiled

for item in List:
    locals()['obj%s' % count] = coherenceEnv.Object(item[:-len(suffix)] + '.o' , item)
    print "obj%s" % count
    ObjectList.append(coherenceEnv.Object(item[:-len(suffix)] + '.o' , item))
    count = count + 1

#
# create a static library using the newly created objects
#

cohLib = cohEnv.StaticLibrary(target = 'riskpo', source = [cohFiles, ObjectList])
cohEnv.Install('#/lib', [cohLib])
```

At the moment this works, however its far from ideal.
Is there a better more straighforward way to do this using basic scons commands,
Also how can I enforce order on the flow of execution using scons.
thanks
D

Answer (score 1):

When migrating from Make to SCons one of the issues people usually run into is understanding that with SCons you don't specify the order, you tell SCons what builds what and then SCons will (usually) connect the dots and figure out the order.

With your perl scripts which generate many .c files, the problem is that SCons doesn't know about those generated files, and so they won't be found, which means that SCons won't know to run the perl script before any steps which use it's outputs.

You should take a look at the user guide, especially the section on emitters for this issue:
http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x3689.html

The wiki is another source for examples.
http://scons.org/wiki/DynamicSourceGenerator
and
http://scons.org/wiki/ToolsForFools

May apply.

Is the list of generated C files static and/or can it be determined by the contents of another file?

Comment: First paragraph, isn't that also what Make does? It's rather unusual for Python though...

Comment: Mark - You are indeed correct, though it's not that uncommon to use it to also enforce order (for which (gnu) make has a specific syntax).   It's basically one of the fundamental mistakes people make when migrating from any other build system to SCons.  I can't tell you how many questions start with I want A to start before B.. how do I enforce the order..

Comment: Yeah that's the wrong way for them to look at the problem. Though I wonder if Make is to blame, maybe it's Python (never thought I'd say those words).

Comment: Mark - Though make can be used correctly, it's pretty easy to and often used incorrectly as a 1/2 measure moving from listing a sequence of commands.